# Calculating the square numbers within a range (python)

Tags: python, iterator

I want to be able to execute the following code:

```
for i in Squares(5, 50):
      print(i)
```

Now this is very easy to implement using a loop, however I want to use an iterator.

So I have defined the following class:

```
import math

class Squares(object):

    def __init__(self, start, stop):
       self.start = start
       self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self): 
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        start = self.start
        stop = self.stop
        squareroot = math.sqrt(start)

        if self.start > self.stop:
            raise StopIteration

        if squareroot == math.ceil(squareroot):
            start += 1
```

But at the moment this is returning `None` an infinite amount of times. This means the none must be because the `StopIteration` is being executed even when it shouldn't. I think my `if squareroot == math.ceil(squareroot):` condition is correct because I tested it separately, but I can't figure out what to change to get the output I want. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: For a code such as:

```
for i in Squares(4, 16):
    print(i)
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
4
9
16
```

Comment: What is the O/P you are expecting? (3,4,5,6,7)?

Comment: You're only incrementing `start` when `start` is a square. That means it gets stuck at the first non-square.

Comment: @ Bhargav Rao I just edited :)

Comment: Perhaps all you need is a Python generator here, just use generator comprehension for a fast and memory efficient solution (see below).

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a generator function:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def Squares(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        sqrti = sqrt(i)
        if sqrti == ceil(sqrti):
            yield i
```

And then loop it:

```
for i in Squares(4, 20):
    print i,
```

which prompts:

```
4 9 16
```

EDIT: edited to match the square definition, not the previous square power (sorry :P). Added +1 to the range to match the question example of the OP.

Comment: That's a generator :d

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to find all squares in a range using an iterator... this is a very good answer, but to a different question.

Comment: @Kittsil I thought it just meant *square* iterator as an iterator that returns the square power of a given number. I edited the answer to provide the proper square definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the arithmetic by using

```
(n + 1)**2 == n**2 + (2*n + 1)
```

Here's how to do that using a generator function:

```
import math

def squares(lo, hi):
    root = int(math.ceil(lo ** 0.5))
    num = root ** 2
    delta = 2 * root + 1
    while num <= hi:
        yield num
        num += delta
        delta += 2

print list(squares(4, 16))
print list(squares(5, 50))
print list(squares(20, 90))
```

**output**

```
[4, 9, 16]
[9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Here's an equivalent iterator class. I've given it a `__repr__` method so it looks nice if you print an instance of this class.

```
import math

class Squares(object):
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        root = int(math.ceil(start ** 0.5))
        self.num = root ** 2
        self.delta = 2 * root + 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Squares(%d, %d)' % (self.start, self.stop)

    def __iter__(self): 
        return self

    def next(self):
        num = self.num
        if num > self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        self.num += self.delta
        self.delta += 2
        return num

sq = Squares(4, 16)
print sq
for i in sq:
    print i

print list(Squares(5, 50))
print list(Squares(20, 90))
```

**output**

```
Squares(4, 16)
4
9
16
[9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
[25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

For Python 3, replace the `next` method name with `__next__`.

The usual Python `range` convention is to stop before you reach the high limit. To make this code comply with that convention, in the `squares()` generator change

```
while num <= hi:
```

to

```
while num < hi:
```

and in the `Squares()` class, change

```
if num > self.stop:
```

to

```
if num >= self.stop:
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to keep incrementing start until it reaches the next square, not to increment it only if it is a square:

```
def __next__(self):
    self.start += 1
    squareroot = math.sqrt(self.start)
    while squareroot != math.ceil(squareroot):
        if self.start > self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        self.start += 1
        squareroot = math.sqrt(self.start)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do this

```
def squares(start, end): 
return [i**2 for i in range(start, end+1) ]
```

so the result for

```
print(squares(1, 5))
```

will be:

> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

```
import math


class Squares(object):

    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self._squares = range(start, stop + 1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._squares.__iter__()

    def __next__(self):
        if math.sqrt(self._squares.next()) == math.ceil(math.sqrt(self._squares.next())): 
            return math.sqrt(self._squares.next()) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in Squares(5, 50):
        print i
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just print all the numbers from 5 to 49?

Comment: I thought this is what OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import ceil, sqrt
start,stop = 4,16
gen_sqr = (  i for i in range( start, stop +1) if sqrt(i) == ceil( sqrt(i)) )
```

Now you have your very own generator of squares:

```
gen_sqr.next() #4
gen_sqr.next() #9
list(gen_sqr) #[16]
```